# Rails routes with wildcard and requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to set up routes wich will match links like this:

```
1: fixed/9731-monday-tuesday-wednesday-thursday-friday/922-another
2: fixed/potatoe
```

First case has unlimited parameters, however all of them are in format [number]-[some-string].
Second case has only one parameter with caracters only.

I'v tried this:

```
   map.connect("/fixed/*param_list",
               :controller => 'first',
               :action => 'index',
               :requirements => {:param_list => /(\d+-[\w-]+)/})

   map.connect("/fixed/:category",
               :controller => 'second',
               :action => 'index')
```

However first route with requirements doesn't work as with wildcard any more. It only match ulr like */fixed/922-another* but not two and more dimensional */fixed/922-another/123-and-more*.

So my question is: **Is possible to parametrized wildcard route via requirments? And how to set up it in my case.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your regexp is wrong. Shouldn't it be `/\d+-[\w-]+(\/\d+-[\w-]+)*/` in order to handle multiple parameters?

Comment: Well, you are right. I've expected that the expression is for each instance of parameter but obviously it has to be for whole part of parameters. Thank you very much.