# Adding Requirements to Globbed Routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, glob

I have a question regarding regex matching on a globbed route in rails 2.3.  This ticket explains exactly the same problem I'm having:
[Rails routes with wildcard and requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326679/rails-routes-with-wildcard-and-requirements)

The problem is that I cannot get the regex for :property_types to match on anything except the first instance of a property types, and that somehow breaks the match on :location_b.

So the following only works if the property_types requirement is removed:

**/for-sale/us/ny/apartment/loft/brooklyn/**

```
map.location ":transaction/:country_code/:location_a/*property_types/:location_b",
  :controller => "search",
  :action => "location",
  :transaction => /(for-sale|for-rent|auction|new_development)/i,
  :country_code => /\w\w/i,
  :location_a => /\w\w/i,
  :property_types => /(apartment|loft|home|condo|multi-home|town-house)/i
```

Hoping someone could explain how I can get the regex for property_types working as I do not understand how it's supposed to work across a glob bed route, which is an array.  The ticket I linked to seems to suggest that it's possible to have the regex match across each type, but I was unable to get anything working.

Example url:
http://localhost:3000/for-sale/us/ny/apartment/loft/brooklyn